# How to reduce data retention period in Azure AppInsight

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

In Azure AppInsight the data retained for 90 days by default. My requirement is to Remove data after every  days interval. Means, AppInsight should have last 2 days data(not more than date).

Any suggestions.

Comment: I wonder, if you are only allowed to have a 2 day retention whether Application Insigths is a good fit.You do know you only pay for the ingress, not for the storage?

Comment: That is the requirement to reduce down the Insight amount of Data.

Comment: As long as it is not done to reduce costs it is ok. Otherwise don't bother because you are not charged for the storage.

Comment: voting to reopen, this is NOT a duplicate of the linked item.  using purge is NOT THE SAME as adjusting retention.  purge is a relatively expensive operation that a resource owner would do to delete *specific* data for a *specific* purpose (like GDPR), and in the grand scheme of things is *expensive*.  The ability to adjust retention directly in the portal is in progress, and instead, you should contact support through the support+troubleshooting item for the resource